# WordPress error "This widget requires javascript"

Tags: javascript, wordpress

My wordpress Website https://www.paramountplus.com.au/ frontend not works in Internet explorer. When i login to admin section from IE i see this error "This widget requires javascript" and the wordpress dashboard menu not works.
Same website i upload in subdomain https://www.test.paramountplus.com.au/ where everything works fine.

I have uninstalled the wordpress from main domain and install a fresh wordpress for test, but same error in main domain.

Please help me to fix this error.

[image]

Comment: Most likely scenario is that javascript is used to remove the message from the dom and that this is failing due to some error in the script, check your browser console for errors

Answer (score 1):

If it works in the other browsers it probably means that:
-you internet explorer version is really old
-you do not have some plugins or javascript enabled

So check for updates and then in settings look for the plugins section and enable javascript

Comment: I am using IE 11 and same website on subdomain works without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with IE, probably. If no JavaScript is executing, this might mean that the browser has JavaScript disabled. Check that first.

Comment: I am using IE 11 and same website on subdomain works without any issue.